# How to derive a 4096 bit or 8192 bit RSA private key from a (BIP39) mnemonic seed?

Tags: rsa

How to derive a 4096 bit or 8192 bit RSA private key from a (BIP39) mnemonic seed?

Any tool available for this?

Comment: You could use the seed to instantiate a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG) and from it generate numbers until you find two primes. You can test if a number is prime efficiently with probabilistic primality tests such as Miller-Rabin.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already pointed out in a comment by @corpsfini, you could use a PRNG to generate pseude-random numbers from the seed. Then you would check whether they are primes using some probabilistic primality test.

In spirit the same procedure is implemented in [this github repo](https://github.com/nomadcrypto/seededrsa) you might find useful.

Comment: That uses a non-secure hash, so I doubt that the PRNG is secure; it actually mentions on the SO post that it is derived from that it isn't. Now possibly this won't be exploitable in the wild, but you'd have to prove that.